# Wordpress injects code to header and footer in Magento Wordpress Integration

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, magento-1.9

I have included wordpress into magento in order to use wordpress functions by adding following lines to magentos `index.php`.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once MAGENTO_ROOT . '/blog/wp-load.php';
```

But this code somehow injects wordpress `wp_head` and `wp_footer` code in header and footer of magento files.

This is my magento template file (`2columns-left.phtml`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

but output is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
    <style type="text/css">
        .mobile-menu {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: -moz-sticky;
            position: -ms-sticky;
            position: -o-sticky;
            position: sticky;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://SITNAME.com/blog/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://SITNAME.com/blog/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cant understand how can wp inject html into header and footer without calling any php function (Note style and script tags). Even I disabled JS too. Any help highly appreciated.

Edit:
This is not magento specific. I include `wp-load.php` into an independent php script and wordpress changes output. Adds style and script in header and before body ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mysterious could you try this in your functions.php and get back to us?

```
function unhook_wp_head_footer(){
  global $wp_filter,$wpdb,$wp_query;

  if(is_page('2columns-left.phtml')) {
    foreach ( $wp_filter['wp_head'] as $priority => $wp_head_hooks ) {
      if( is_array( $wp_head_hooks ) ) {
        foreach ( $wp_head_hooks as $wp_head_hook ) {
          remove_action( 'wp_head', $wp_head_hook['function'], $priority );
        }
      }
    }

    foreach ($wp_filter['wp_footer'] as $priority => $wp_footer_hooks ) {
      if( is_array( $wp_footer_hooks ) ){
        foreach ( $wp_footer_hooks as $wp_footer_hook ) {
          remove_action( 'wp_footer', $wp_footer_hook['function'], $priority );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'unhook_wp_head_footer' );
```

Comment: thanks man.. works but does not work if i hook into wp action. If i use it without any action then it works. trying to find out an appropriate hook now. Also you have an idea where should i include this code? how about index.php of magento?

Comment: @mysterious try 'init' hook. It's a wordpress installation so, as I've mentioned above functions.php file would be fine(child theme or not). If it's working without the hook just do not use one. Glad I could help.

Comment: I will try init. I didn't put it in functions.php cause I set WP_USE_THEMES to  false. Thanks for putting me on right track. Bounty awarded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want WordPress integration with Magento then you need to use fishpig extension  follow this URL 
https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/

Comment: lets forget integration. My question is how wordpress can inject code into a php file that contains only html.

Comment: so far what i think is wp search for body and head tag in final output and then adds its code before sending to browser.